How do I develop prediction intervals for Reinforcement Learning?
I recently learned about the concept of prediction intervals (for regression) and I would like to apply them to my Deep Reinforcement Learning algorithm. I am working with a Model-Free RL algorithm with continuous action spaces. That means the neural network takes in some state vector as input and returns a (usually scalar) action.
Based on the article linked over here, one strategy would be run my DRL network multiple times within an environment and record the action values for every state. This should give me a range of values that could be used to compute the prediction interval.
Would my approach work? Is there an alternative better approach? Please let me know if something sounds wrong or isn't clear.

Prediction of what, the outcome upon taking a certain action?

No, the action value is the prediction. The neural network f is a non-linear function, s.t f:S->A

Quantiles of point predictions of multiple runs of a model will not give you a prediction interval. This will give you a confidence interval for the point prediction, and there is a difference. CIs on point predictions will be (far) narrower than PIs. If this is what the linked article advocates (I did not read it in depth, but that does seem to be the case), then it is simply wrong. Try this in an experiment yourself, with simulated N(0,1) data with no useful predictors: the "PI" will be far away from an interval containing (say) 95% of realizations.
What you can do, and this is a common approach: develop a probabilistic model, i.e., one whose output is not just a point prediction, but an entire predictive density. You may be able to make some distributional assumptions, e.g., assume a conditional normal distribution of your outcome, then you "only" need to predict the mean and the variance. Once you have such a prediction, sample from it many times. Then take quantiles of these realizations. (Note the difference between taking quantiles of simulated realizations versus quantiles of point predictions. The approach I propose incorporates the modeled residual variability. The other does not. Therefore the approach I propose yields prediction intervals, the other one confidence intervals on the point predictions.)
You can combine this with the "run multiple models" approach: run multiple models (e.g. through bootstrapping, or using different random initializations, etc.), and simulate from the predictive density for each separate run. Then collect these many realizations, and calculate intervals from those. This accounts, to a degree, for model and parameter uncertainty.
Note that this is not specific to Reinforcement Learning, but works for any prediction model. RL comes in when you "do something" with the PIs. You might be interested in tools to evaluate the quality of PIs as described here. (Full disclosure: I wrote that section. Note that it also applies in non-time series situations.)
